# Redirect to Login Page if windows authentication cancel button is clicked

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, forms-authentication, redirect, windows-authentication

I have FBA enabled on my SharePoint 2016 Web application, I have made custom login form.
In that form I have given SP Admin login link, visible only for SharePoint User group.

When I click on that SharePoint Login link, it loads the windows authentication form that I achieved as below screen:

[image]

Now when I click on `Cancel` button it redirects me to the below error page:

[image].

So my question here is, is it possible to achieve if I click on `Cancel` button of form authentication, it should redirect me to the login page?

I have tried this approach to set custom error page in `web.config`

```
<customErrors mode="On"defaultRedirect="/login.aspx">
```

but this will redirect in every situation when error is occurring, I only want to have this when click on `Cancel` of authentication form is occured.

So is this achievable?